# Right to left gradient in iE with css - possible?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Is it possible to create a right to left gradient in IE 5-9? In IE 10 it is possible, but is it in earlier versions without using an image?

Left to right gradients in earlier versions:

```
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#D5D4D4, endColorStr=#FFFFFFFF, GradientType=1);

/* For Internet Explorer 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#D5D4D4, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF, GradientType=1)";
```

In IE 10 there is the option to change gradient direction:

```
/* For Internet Explorer 10 */
-ms-linear-gradient(left, #D5D4D4, #fff 45%);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12703331/1012591

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Just do:

```
/* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#FFFFFFFF, endColorStr=#D5D4D4, GradientType=1);

/* For Internet Explorer 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFFFF, endColorstr=#D5D4D4, GradientType=1)";
```

---

Serious answer: the [gradient `filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) support two [gradients types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): 0 (vertical) and 1 (horizontal).

If you want to switch from right->lef to left->right , you need to switch the `start` and `end` color hex.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe all I should have done is to think the other way around!